# Android emulator map is not visible

Tags: android, google-maps

I have added a MapView element in my android project. The project is not showing any error, but when i run the application on my emulator (Google API 2.2), the map isn't visible. Instead only the grid lines are seen. The DDMS is giving me "java.net.UnknownHostException: android.clients.google.com" exception. I have already added INTERNET permission in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a  Map's API key from google to see the map.

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

In this link there is described how to use the mapview.

Comment: I have already added the API key... and I'm using the same site for tutorials. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me: I followed the tutorial, opened the application, and all I got was grid lines.  In my case, my computer was attached to working internet, but my Android device was attached to a network that had become broken.